# Servlet does not load on startup

Tags: java, servlets

Even if the `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` the servlet does not auto-load

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.mycompany.MyRestletApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

```
public class MyRestletApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public Restlet createInboundRoot() {

    String process = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
    System.out.println("Started with Process id: " + process);

    Router router = new Router(getContext());
    router.attachDefault(ServerResource.class);

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
      System.out.println("Terminating database");
    }));

    return router;
  }
}
```

What could be missing here?

Comment: Which container are you running in? What log output do you get on startup? How do you know it doesn't auto load?

Comment: It does not print the log

Comment: MyRestletApplication is being passed as a parameter to the Servlet class. It is the servlet class that is loaded on startup.